# Display flickers occasionally on Opera

Tags: 16.04, display, opera, flicker

Hy,
I recently moved to Opera on Ubuntu 16.04 since I always used it for my Windows PC. The problem is that sometimes when I scroll the browser or play videos (noticed on Facebook videos mostly) the display flickers.

**opera://gpu** returns the following:
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CO7W.png)

Laptop specifications are the following: [laptop specs](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/NX.GD6AA.003)

P.S.: I would gladly attach more information if needed to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this issue by disabling Hardware Acceleration. Go to settings in Opera. Click on "Browser". Check the box in the bottom left-hand corner "Show Advanced Settings". Scroll until you see "Use Hardware Acceleration when available" and un-check it. This will require a restart of the browser to take affect. Hope this helps anyone in the future experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the acceleration option works but causes a jerky scrolling of pages after that.  If you want smooth scrolling you need this option checked.  So far you can't have both...no flashing of pages and smooth scrolling.  I find Firefox is the only browser that doesn't have this problem.  Opera being the worst.